# Which tts engine is voicerss.org using?

Tags: text-to-speech

The voices used by http://www.voicerss.org are really good. Does anybody has an idea what tts engine is used for voicerss.org?

Answer (score 3):

It could be powered by anything, I can't see anything on the front-end which gives the game away.  The server is running Microsoft IIS and the speech API uses ASP/.NET, which might rule out linux-based solutions like Festival. The server might be acting as a "proxy" or pass-thru for another service though. The API page lists supported codecs and languages which might also help you pinpoint it.

They offer a reasonably priced API and a good service. Why not be a customer?

Comment: Thank you for your observations. I already looked at the details and was not able to identify a tts engine from those. 
"They offer a reasonably priced API and a good service. Why not be a customer?" Are you a customer or do you have any other connections to  voicerss.org?

Comment: @tobltobs Sorry then I couldn't be helpful. No, I hadn't heard of them until your question, and I needed a TTS API for a weekend project. You helped me at least :)